# php delete image from server after upload & display

Tags: php, html, image

Sending an image in my php form, it gets saved onto my server and at the
action.php page it gets displayed. Now when I try to:

```
echo '<div id="image"><img src="'.$target_path.'" width="280" height="280"></div>';
```

it works just fine... but if I add `unlink($target_path);` at the end of my php code it
will not even display the image even though it gets deleted AFTER displaying the image...

So the question is, how can I display the image and deleting it at the same time so my server does not gets stuffed with user pictures?

Comment: Your image is deleted *before* your browser fetches it. Your HTML page is retrieved first and before the browser is able to get the image, the `unlink` command is already executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try another thing: output the image base-64 encoded.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$base64 = base64_encode($contents);
echo '<div id="image"><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$base64.'" width="280" height="280"></div>';
```

(instead of `move_uploaded_file()` etc, use as $file variable the `$_FILES[...]['tmp_name']`)

Comment: That's rather expensive, it costs a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: yes (factor 8/5), but this method works without problems and hacks ;) (Is 8/5 so much...?)

Comment: @MrMadMan fyi: you may have to change `image/jpg` to `image/png` etc. depending on which file type you're using.

Comment: and what if i want to support as many types as possible (jpg, png, gif, jpeg, etc.)?

Comment: @MrMadMan do some switch: `switch (strtolower($extension)) { case "jpg": case "jpeg": $mime = "image/jpg"; break; case "png": $mime = "image/png"; break; case "...": $mime = "..."; }`

Comment: uum, where do i put this? what context?

Comment: okay, for some reason my editor doesn't like the last bit: `break; case "...": ...;` and where does $extension come from? $base64?

Comment: `$extension` is the last part of your filename I suppose? The `...` is to show you that you can continue the switch for other cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by creating a little script that gets the image-filename and will delete it after it has been retrieved:

```
<?php
$file = image_file_from_parameter($_GET['image']); 
headers_for_file($file);
readfile($file);
unlink($file);
```

In your HTML output you then link to that script:

```
<img src="path/to/image.php?image=893sudfD983D" />
```

If you set nice caching headers, the user won't notice that your server did serve the file only once.

Comment: if i add this on the top of my page, it loads a blank page

Comment: It'd be an idea to define the functions `image_file_from_parameter` and `headers_for_file` yourself...

Comment: @MrMadMan  you have to check first if $_GET['image'] is set or it will throw some error. and the function headers_for_file and image_file_from_parameter doesn't exist. you should write that to actually set the correct headers

Answer (score 1):

When you echo the url of an image with `img src` you're just sending the browser the url of an image, not the actual image data. The image needs to remain on the server if you want it to be viewable by this approach.

You could use bwoebi's solution to pass the actual image data instead of a link, but a better solution is just to keep the images on the server and periodically delete old files.